# Creating a pull request in Bitucket: error "Unrelated branches"

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm having a small team working on a single repository, I asked my each teammates to create there own branch and work on there branch, all of them cloned the repository and then they did the following command:

```
git checkout -b BitPankaj
```

`BitPankaj` is illustration branch name, they started working on this branch and uploaded there work through

```
git branch --set-upstream origin BitPankaj
```

Now in my repository I can see that those branch appears and their commits are also visible:

[image: commits section]

and Branches:

[image: branches section]

Now each one of them where trying to create a pull request to review there code and merge to master branch. so they tried doing something like this:

But it throws an error of unrelated branches:

> The following error(s) occurred saving this pull request: Unrelated branches

[image: pull request error]

We people are learning to work on git, help me out with this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This is because the `BitPankaj` branch is an orphan branch.**

That means the branch `BitPankaj` didn’t created from `master` branch (as you expected), but may use `git checkout --orphan BitPankaj` instead. The branch structure looks like:

```
A---B---…---C   master
D---…---E    BitPankaj
```

You can double check in your local repo. Update/pull the branches and show logs as graph:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout BitPankaj
git pull BitPankaj
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all 
#Or you can use gitk --all if you installed git bash
```

In order to  create pull request between `BitPankaj` and `master`, you should **change `BitPankaj` branch based from `master` branch**.

- To change `BitPankaj` based from the latest version (commit `C`) of `master` branch:

  ```
  git rebase master BitPankaj
  git push -f origin BitPankaj
  ```

  Then the commit history will like:

  ```
  A---B---…---C   master
               \
                D---…---E   BitPankaj
  ```
- To changes `BitPankaj` branch based from an old version (such as commit `B`) of `master` branch:

  ```
  git rebase <commit id for B> BitPankaj
  git push -f origin BitPankaj
  ```

  Then the commit history will like:

  ```
  A---B---…---C   master
       \
        D---…---E   BitPankaj
  ```

Then you can create pull request to merge `BitPankaj` into `master` branch on bitbucket successfully.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use --allow-unrelated-histories to force the merge to happen.

You should be able to use it like:-

```
git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories
```

for extra info have a look at:-

[Git Merge Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories)

Comment: I don't want to merge them before reviewing the code with other team members, so for this I need to have pull requests before. is there any way to allow unrelated histories in my bit bucket account?

Comment: this has the advantage to maintain the git history as it is. Rebasing rewrites it.