# git - Pull request in Bitbucket: unrelated branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I create another project with its branches and when I created pull request for main which contains the old version of the project ,it shows me this error:
=> **The following error(s) occurred saving this pull request
Unrelated branches**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46157540/13855094 This may help